# Strange behavior of python ternary if operator

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I has writing a simple heap class, not that is relevant. In the `init` function of the class i write the following piece of code

```
def __init__(self, fn=None):
    self.heap = ["start"]  
    self.size_ = 0
    # condition of heap for no change to happen. default is min heap
    self.fn = lambda parent_, child_: (parent_ < child_) if fn is None else fn
```

When i use the self.fn function (when i pass an argument and not None) it will not work. For example when I say

```
maxHeap = BinaryQueue(fn=lambda x, y: x > y)
print(maxHeap.fn(3, 4))
```

It will output `<function <lambda> at 0x00000135EB76D1E0>`

if i write

```
def __init__(self, fn=None):
    self.heap = ["start"] 
    self.size_ = 0
    # condition of heap for no change to happen. default is min heap
    if fn is None:
        self.fn = lambda parent_, child_: parent_ < child_
    else:
        self.fn = fn
```

it will correctly output `False` since `3>4 is False`

Any ideas why the ternary version is not working? (using python 3.6)

Comment: (lambda parent_, child_: (parent_ < child_)) if (fn is None) else fn

Comment: Oh! It needed parenthesis around the lambda function!!. Thank you

Comment: You are right. I can put the lambda in the init call

Comment: @yelq thank you for your time!

Comment: no problem, glad to help!